# Convert "Sun Jul 15 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)" to YYYY-mm-dd in php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using datepicker plugin from eyecon.ro and I got selected date with `$('input').DatePickerGetDate();`.

The output is: `Sun Jul 15 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)`

How to convert it to be `Y-m-d` format?

I've tried these:

1. `$('input').DatePickerGetDate("YY-mm-dd");`
2. `$('input').DatePickerGetDate("Y-m-d");`
3. `$('input').DatePickerGetDate("YYYY-mm-dd");`

but the result is just the same: `Sun Jul 15 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)`

Comment: It looks like you would need to call [formatDate()](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) on the object before getting the date, but I haven't looked very deeply into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While initialising the datepicket add format option

```
$('.input').DatePicker({
    format:'Y-m-d',
    date: $('.input').val(),
    current: $('.input').val(),
     ....//rest of your initialising code
```

and access the data using

```
$('.input').DatePickerGetDate(true);
```

Hope this helps..